# Is SQLite cursor.getCount expensive operation in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Is **SQLite cursor.getCount()** expensive operation when executed on **Android** device?

Which is faster:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
int length = cursor.getCount();
final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(length * 2); // need maybe 2 items per row

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

      // loop trough the query result
      do {
...
```

or

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();  // capacity is 0 by default on android

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

      // loop trough the query result
      do {
```

Comment: I don't think there's significant difference in performance, unless you're talking considerable amount/size of elements. Otherwise, I think your question offers some subject to discuss as: is it better to allocated memory in advance on your phone to gain performance...

Comment: I don't think there's ever a difference in performance. `cursor.moveToFirst()` calls `onMove` which calls `getCount`. So getCount can be very slow, but you can't really escape it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you compare the time required for both code samples to execute, you'll notice it's the same because [`Cursor.moveToFirst()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#AbstractCursor.moveToPosition%28int%29) is eventually calling `SQLiteCursor.getCount()`

Comment: This is correct, I tested both code samples on a large db with query that takes 30 seconds to complete and the time was same.

Comment: I think, Ionut Negru has answered your question :)