# Android: cursor.getCount()

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, cursor

I'm wondering if there is any alternative for cursor.getCount() which is way too expensive! My goal is to run one query first, if cursor is null or cursor.getCount() <=0 then I will need to run another query.

But since the underlying data can be large, I was getting Application Not Responding for the getCount() call. any better solution to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cursor is empty, moveToFirst will be false

Comment: moveToFirst() is still expensive, isn't it?

Comment: and `moveToFirst()` eventually calls `cursor.getCount()`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25119511/609782

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in finding out whether the table has any rows at all, then one very optimal query would be:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM <tableName>);
```

This does not scan the entire table unlike `count()`, and it execute in under two milliseconds for a table with 250,000+ records on an iPhone, so it definitely scales with size.

Comment: And then? check the count of cursor?

Comment: @Darpan the count of the cursor for this query will always be 1. It will yield exactly one row with a value of either 0, or 1. 0 means no matching rows were found. 1 means that at least one matching row was found.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to avoid using [`Cursor.getCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount()) because most (if not all?) [`Cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) methods eventually call it. [See the source code for yourself](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#moveToNext).

Maybe try using the `limit` clause in the query and set the limit to 1, then checking the cursor returned from the query to see if it is empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

Run the first query with limited fields. For example, the first query may run only for _id.

Comment: yes, that's what i do. i query one column only but still has the issue. is there a way we can check if the 1st row is null?

Comment: You can run a query to get only the 1st row with "where" clause; "_id = 0", it will get you only the first row.